# Using population data as Z-axis to make 3D map in Python?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, 3d-map

I want to make a 3D thematic map with the different status' population data as the height in Python. I have the shapefile of the status and the population data, although I don't know how to set the population attribute data as the Z-axis. I want to make a map like the following.

Is there a python package that allows the 3-D mapping of shapefiles such that I can specify an attribute as the Z value?

[image]